# Debugging without .pdb files in Visual Studio

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2005

I am working on a project where I do not have access to the .pdb files required for debugging which is causing my break points not to work when debugging.

I have no way of getting these .pdb files, is there any other way I can getting breakpoints to work when debugging in Visual Studio in 2005.

Comment: you of course can free set breakpoints in asm code. you try set bps in src code ? have src but not have pdb ? impossible set bp in src code without information how convert src lines to binary address. and this information exist only in pdb

Comment: I'm sorry I don't follow what you are saying.

Comment: is it .net assembly? native one?

Comment: .net version is 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this issue by downloading new PDBs using the required DLLs with [PDB Downloader](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webtopics/2016/03/07/pdb-downloader/)

Comment: but it looks like this tool only downloads Microsoft PDBs - what that the case that you were missing as you did not mentioned it in the question?

Comment: they were all MS PDBs, not sure if it works for non-MS PDBs

Comment: ok, and I guess VS 2005 doesn't support getting the PDBs from withing the IDE so you couldn't use that

Comment: if it does I couldn't figure out how to, but I can't say for sure it doesn't

Answer (score 2):

You can't debug if you don't have PDBs but...

JetBrains' dotPeek can act as a Symbol Server for your assemblies. You can setup it to provide the PDBs for the code that you don't have the PDBs. It will create files on the way.

[Using dotPeek as a Symbol Server](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/decompiler/Using_product_as_a_Symbol_Server.html)

Comment: Is there no way to generate new ones? I can't use a symbol server due to the sensitivity of the application the development machine is not permitted to be online.

Comment: I see I can install a stand alone dotPeek symbol server, but it doesn't appear to support .net 2.0

Comment: symbol server runs locally on your machine. As for the .net 2.0 let me check that

Comment: @mgrenier no, I have no issue with providing symbols for a simple .net 2.0 app - iif it doesn't work for you it has to be different issue. Maybe dotPeek itself requires .net higher than 2.0 but it has no issue with providing symbols for apps that uses older ones